# Angular Scope in a controller

Tags: angularjs, controller, angularjs-scope

"Angular version": "1.3.8",

I have the following code
The controller is being delivered to the page like so

```
'use strict';

/**
 * @ngdoc overview
 * @name testApp
 * @description
 * # testApp
 *
 * Main module of the application.
 */
angular
  .module('testApp', [
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngCookies',
    'ngMessages',
    'ngResource',
    'ngRoute',
    'ngSanitize',
    'ngTouch'
  ])
  .config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
      })
      .when('/about', {
        templateUrl: 'views/about.html',
        controller: 'AboutCtrl'
      })
      .when('/test', {
        templateUrl: 'views/test.html',
        controller: 'MyCtrl'
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
  });
```

in a test.html file

```
<div>
  <input ng-model="expr" type="text" placeholder="Enter an expression" />
  <h2>{{parsedValue}}</h2>
</div>
```

in a controller.js file

```
'use strict';
angular.module('testApp').controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $parse) {
  $scope.$watch('expr', function(newVal, oldVal, scope) {
    if (newVal !== oldVal) {
      // Let's set up our parseFun with the expression
      var parseFun = $parse(newVal);
      // Get the value of the parsed expression
      $scope.parsedValue = parseFun(scope);
    }
  });
});
```

1. When running the code above the bound variable  `{{parsedValue}}` isn't being updated.
2. Debugging the code shows me that `$scope.parsedValue` is undefined after the assignment.
3. Why all the decorum to create the `parseFun` ( i get that it may be a closure to keep all values )  but it doesn't work

Could someone shine some light as to what is going on....There is another similar question here but I believe that question had some issues because of the way it was asked.

Comment: The parsing and referring to the value on scope works: http://plnkr.co/edit/Ch2WFP3XGRvCySFh4UXz?p=preview (try entering `x + 1` in the input box. However, since the change function is called very often, you should cycle through several variable names which indeed are `undefined` on the `$scope`. Actually, in your given example, _all_ values on the scope will be undefined since you do not have any variables defined and only primitive expressions (e.g. `1 + 2` or `"test"`) will work. That probably is not what you want. What values are you typing into the input box?

Comment: Is this the behavior you want instead: http://plnkr.co/edit/B1IDO8we71pB4VJnG8RH?p=preview ?

Comment: Thank you. Your explanation makes things very clear. I was following an example and the author wasn't very clear about what he was trying to accomplish....Thanks a million

Comment: In that case, I'll post the comments as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parsing and referring to the value on scope works: http://plnkr.co/edit/Ch2WFP3XGRvCySFh4UXz?p=preview

Since the change function is called very often, the code cycles through several variable names which indeed are undefined on `$scope`. Actually, in the given example, all values on the scope will be `undefined` since there aren't any variables defined and only primitive expressions (e.g. `1 + 2` or `"test"`) will work. In the linked example, the variable `x` can be used in the inputted expression.

However, that probably is not what you want.

To be able to replicate user's input as a `string`, you do not need to `$parse` the expression.
Instead, just the following will work:

```
<input ng-model="expr" type="text" placeholder="Enter some text">
<h2>{{expr}}</h2>
```

without the need of any code on the controller.